# Prevent sharing login credentials between users in WCF

Tags: wcf, security, authentication, azure

I have a service hosted in a Worker Role in Azure. Clients connect over NetTcp bindings using certificates for mutual client/service authentication and with a custom username password validation.

Clients also receive event notifications that are broadcast through the Azure service bus using shared secret authentication.

I want this to be secure and not allow one person to share his/her login information with friends or anyone else - their login is for their use only. Similarly, a user that forgets to log off at one machine and then logs in to the service from another machine (i.e. tablet, work computer etc.) should trigger a automatic shutdown of the application that was not logged off from.

I am using a per-call serivce, and to have implement a solution using sessions would require alot of rewiring.

I figure I need to keep track of the users' context when they make a operation call and track which IPs are currently using that login/credential. I would like to be able to have some kind of "death touch" whereby the service can send a kill command to a client when multiple logins are detected.

Any suggestions or pointers to patterns that deal with this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: What about users that are behind the same router and have the same public IP?  What about users that use a proxy, again giving them the same IP?  What happens when a users account gets hacked?  Now they can't log in and change their password because the hacker keeps logging in and kicking them out before they can get to the change password screen.

Comment: Yes, that is something that will have to be addressed. Would you suggest allowing a user to login from a tight-subnet (address range) -- anything outside of that subnet would be disallowed? I know it is not a simple solution... I do need to prevent this from happening however. Thanks for your input.

Comment: I wouldn't worry about it.  Are you just trying prevent revenue loss?  Or is this an extra layer of security?

Comment: Revenue loss is a concern. Is this kind of functionality not implemented for web services? Security is a top priority with this application and any loose ends should ideally be tied up before launch. Additionally, what would stop a large group of users using one login between them all?

Comment: Does your client keep connections open? My understanding is that a client should open the connection, perform an operation and then close the connection. If the operations happen rather quickly, you aren't likely to have the same user connected simultaneously from multiple clients.

Comment: Ultimately though, you can't control your users. If they give away their own login information, that's their loss.

Comment: Very true.  How can you log a person out of a WCF service when you're only "there" for a fraction of a second.  I guess you can have a user table with thier IP and if their IP doesn't match on the next WCF call, you can "log them out" - whatever that means.

Comment: Your applicaton would have to repeatly ping your WCF service to see if you're still logged in or not.  The benefits are not obvious to me.

Comment: The fact is, some people are not going to want to pay for your product.  Look at things like the Humble Indie Bundle.  They give it away and still makes tons of money.  The Oatmeal just raised $100,000 in a few days and the people that contributed didn't get anything out of it.  Create a good product, engage your customers, make them feel good about paying you.  That will do more for you than any form of DRM or connection monitoring.

Comment: Note: I'm not saying a pay what you want model works for everyone, just that if you focus on extracting money from your customers, that means you are not focusing on your customers.

Comment: @cadrell0 I agree that a product should be worthy of its price. I plan to offer something that my target user group will find very useful. I guess your right, if someone wants to share their login then there is nothing I can do about it. Just wanted to get some feedback on the subject and am grateful I did. Thanks all.

Comment: @DanAndrews Your correct, I did not look at the issue from that angle. No real benefit from that perspective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you did go with PerSession you would still need to determine if the same user was in more than one session and you have the overhead of session.

I have only tested this over WSHttpBinding and not hosted in an Azure Role so please don't vote it down if it does not work on NetTcp Azure Role - comment and I will delete it.  Even with PerCall the SessionID is durable and SessionID is available on both the client and server.  More than one user could have the same IP address but SessionID is unique to the session.  Clearly you would need to record the userID, SessionID but table storage is cheap.

Maybe update license model for concurrent usage.  By recording userID and sessionID you could write an algorithm to calculate max concurrent usage.

Comment: Thanks for the useful suggestion, I figured some kind of table would be needed to track current users. I will make a suitable stipulation in the license model. Marked as answer.

Comment: Since is it just the two keys table storage should work pretty good since it has partition key and row key. I am adding exactly this to an application I am responsible for.